# Minimal injective extension is rigid

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, positivity

Let $V$ be an operator system.

**Definition 1:** A pair $(W, \kappa)$ is called extension of $V$ if $W$ is an operator system and $\kappa: V \to W$ is a unital complete isometry.

**Definition 2:** An extension $(W,\kappa)$ of $V$ is called injective extension if $W$ is an injective operator system.

**Definition 3**: An extension $(W, \kappa)$ of $V$ is called rigid if for every unital completely positive map $\varphi: W \to W$ with $\varphi \kappa = \kappa$, we necessarily have $\varphi = \iota_W$.

**Definition 4**: An injective extension $(W,\kappa)$ of $V$ is called minimal if $\kappa(V)\subseteq W_1 \subseteq W$ with $W_1$ injective implies that $W_1 = W.$

**Question**: Is a minimal injective extension necessarily rigid? Is there a quick way to see this? I have a rather long argument along the lines of stuff in Paulsen where we use minimal seminorms, but maybe there is an easier way. If it helps, I know that for injective extensions, rigidity = essentiality.

Comment: Probably I'm missing something- but isn't Fix($\phi$), the set of fixed points of $\phi$, an injective operator system contained in W, that contains $\kappa(V)$? By minimality of $W$, we then have Fix($\phi$)$=W$, proving rigidity.

Comment: @DarthVader Why is $\operatorname{Fix}(\varphi)$ injective?

Comment: If $W$ is an operator system, and $\phi$ a ucp map on $W$, then there exists a "conditional expectation" from W to Fix($\phi$). Define $E: W \rightarrow Fix(\phi)$ by $E(w)= \lim_{N \rightarrow \omega} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N \phi^n(w)$, where $\omega$ is a nonprincipal ultrafilter. As $W$ is injective, so is $Fix(\phi)$, by composition of "conditional expectations".

Comment: @DarthVader Thanks! I'm definitely not familiar with such an approach. Do you have a reference for this? You may also want to write an answer.

Comment: The conditional expectation defined here is same as Hamana's approach in "injective operator systems" paper. There he defines the "minimal projections" by looking at similar limits. Probably Paulsen's book also has similar approaches in various proofs- but I will have to check.

Comment: @DarthVader Ah okay, I think I see what you are referring to! The word non-principal ultrafilter threw me off (I'm not really familiar with filters). But basically you mean something like take a limit point (for the point $\sigma$-weak topology as Hamana refers to it) of the sequence of averages to construct the map $E$? Thanks again!

Comment: That's what I had in mind

Comment: @DarthVader Alright! Thanks. You may want to write an answer.

Comment: You are very welcome :). I posted this as an answer.

Comment: @DarthVader It's not clear to me how you define $E: W \to Fix(\phi)$. In what sense are you taking an ultralimit?

Comment: @DarthVader It is not clear to me why the map you obtain from taking this limit works. Moreover, there seems to be an additional technicality. I think to apply the compactness of the space we must view the net of UCP maps in $UCP(W, B(H))$ with enlargened codomain. Then your limit is a map $W \to B(H)$. Maybe we can compose with a conditional expectation $B(H) \to W$ (exists by injectivity of $W$) to solve the latter problem, but even then it is not clear to me why it works.

Comment: @JessePeterson: You are right in your objection. I was following Skalski's argument (https://www.isibang.ac.in/~jay/OTOA/OTOA16/slides/Adam.pdf)
but he needs $\phi$ to be normal. And of course, $W$ need not be weakly closed here, so extending the map $\phi$ to $B(H)$ also doesn't help with this argument of construction of $E$.

Comment: @DarthVader If you manage to fix the argument and show that $\operatorname{Fix}(\varphi)$ is injective, I would be glad to see that!

Comment: Paulsen's book contains a proof, so I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for. See corollary 15.7.

Answer (score 3):

Hamana's proof (Theorem 3.5 in Injective Envelopes of Operator Systems, PubL RIMS, Kyoto Univ. 15 (1979), 773-785) is fairly direct. Consider the partial ordering on the space $\Xi = \{ \phi \in UCP(W, W) \mid \phi \kappa = \kappa \}$ given by $\phi \prec \psi$ when $\| \phi(x) \| \leq \| \psi(x) \|$ for all $x \in W$. First, note that every element in $\Xi$ dominates a minimal element in $\Xi$ since if $\{ \phi_i \}_i$ is a decreasing net in $\Xi$, then taking any concrete realization $W \subset \mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ we have $E \phi \prec \phi_i$ for all $i$, where $E: \mathcal B(\mathcal H) \to W$ is any ucp idempotent and $\phi$ is any limit point of $\{ \phi_i \}_i$ in $UCP(W, \mathcal B(\mathcal H))$, which is compact in the topology of pointwise ultraweak convergence.

Second, note that any minimal element $\phi \in \Xi$ is an idempotent. Indeed, for any $N \geq 1$ and $x \in W$ we have $\| \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n = 1}^N \phi^n( x ) \| \leq \| \phi(x) \|$ and so by minimality it follows that this is equality. Considering $x = y - \phi(y)$ we have $\| \phi(y) - \phi^2(y) \| = \| \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n = 1}^N \phi^n(y - \phi(y) ) \| \leq \frac{2}{N} \| y \| \to 0$.

Thus, if every idempotent in $\Xi$ is the identity, it follows that the identity is the only map in $\Xi$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varphi: W \rightarrow W$ be a u.c.p map.

Let Fix$(\varphi)=\{ w \in W: \varphi(w)=w\}$.

Then, Fix$(\varphi)$ is an injective operator system, if $W$ is an injective operator system.
Moreover, Fix$(\varphi)$ contains $\kappa(V)$, as $\varphi \circ \kappa= \kappa$.

By minimality of $W$, we must therefore have that Fix$(\varphi)= W$, thereby establishing rigidity.

Comment: I think you should justify that $\operatorname{Fix}(\varphi)$ is injective! This is non-obvious to me, if it is even true at all!